# How to sort a table column by clicking on the header in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-ui, tablesorter

I want to sort a table column strings values by clicking on table header.
here I did alphabets sorting.
please change this code to String column sorting.

```
enter code here
  var  sortOrder = -1;
    $(".sort").click(function () {
        sortOrder *= -1;
     sortTable($(this));
     });


  function sortTable(element) {
    var tbody = element.parent();
    var colIndex = element.index() -1;
    tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b)
    {
        $('td', a).eq(colIndex).text() === "" ? $('td', a).eq(colIndex).text("0") :   $('td', a).eq(colIndex).text();
        if (sortOrder === 1)
        {
            return parseInt($('td', a).eq(colIndex).text(), 10) - parseInt($('td', b).eq(colIndex).text(), 10);
        }
        else
        {
            return parseInt($('td', b).eq(colIndex).text(), 10) - parseInt($('td', a).eq(colIndex).text(), 10);
        }

    }).appendTo(tbody);
    tbody.find('tr').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass();
        zebra = zebra === 'odd' ? 'even' : 'odd';
        $(this).addClass(zebra);
        $(this).find("td").eq(colIndex).text() === 0 ? $(this).find("td").eq(colIndex).text(""):$(this).find("td").eq(colIndex).text(); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you try to implement a "DataTable" ? Is a good library and those functions already exists, easy and funny : https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 1):

use the jquery datatable js there you will get sorting option as default and also you can use more options called filter,pagination,etc...
[reference](https://datatables.net/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It's Working!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery plugin to sort tables: http://tablesorter.com/

Comment: Thank you. It's Working!

Comment: the arrows are maybe linked in the css -> url(path/to/arrow.png)
check your console for 404 and ajust the links.